# I want google maps API autocomplete to search towns in a specific city only

Tags: javascript, google-maps, autocomplete

I am trying to get the only `Town Names` in an input field using google maps API. The following is the image of what I am working on.

[Screenshot of my input fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFD9E.jpg)

So, I have entered all my cities in the first select field and I have used google maps autocomplete API on the second input field. I have used country restriction on it and country restriction is working fine as I want.

But now the point is that I want it to autocomplete only town names in input field from the selected city only, so please provide some help in this respect.

Following is the code that I am using in this respect.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function findPropertyLocation(){

    var options = {
      componentRestrictions: {country: "pk"}
     };

    var input = document.getElementById('location-search');
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

}
```

Comment: You can not restrict Google's Autocomplete to a city or locality. Per the Docs: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#ComponentRestrictions "country" is the only component restriction allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly, what you can do is set Bounds to set boundaries in the search,

Learn more about Bounds and you will find a way:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#set_search_area